# Notepad-like app with no ability to save

Tags: windows, text-editor, note-taking

Is there a notepad-like app with no toolbars, menus or an ability to save? We have this special requirement for this kind of tool. I saw an app fitting this exact description a couple of years back but I can't remember what it's called. I've been googling for an hour to no avail. :)

Comment: I would perhaps write such a tool for you but ... How do you open files?

Comment: If you google for "distraction free writing", you'll find many tools that have a minimalistic UI. However, they all have a possibility to save, it's just not obvious. [Q10](http://www.baara.com/q10/) is one of them. Just make sure you run the installer as administrator. To end the application press Alt+F4.

Comment: @Thomas - Thanks for the reply! :) We have no need to open files. :) Users would just need have something where they can place random notes while their main tool (slow CRM) is loading. :)

Comment: Oh, now I see! Then these distration free tools are probably not an option, because they run in full screen mode.

Comment: Unfortunately, those does not fill the requirement. The workstations are locked down and only their CRM (the slow beast) and one note-taking app are allowed to run. In addition, the note-taking app should not be able to save. :)

Comment: paper and pen? Or do you need to ensure nothing leaves the location?

Comment: Yes. That's the aim. :)

Comment: I'm wondering if an app such as NotePad has permissions assigned in Windows environment. If so, you could deny the app privileges to write in any folder/directory. Just a thought (I do not know about Windows OS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments have already pointed out, most software which allows users to enter data also allows for them to save their data.
Perhaps the best bet would be to create your own application with a large text field.
[This tiny tutorial](http://csharp.net-informations.com/gui/cs-textbox.htm) is already too in-depth for what you wish to achieve, but it's the lowest-level tutorial I could find on short notice :)